# Как сделать url для многочисленной фильтрации?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

Использую фильтрацию которую предлагает JeffreyWay `https://github.com/laracasts/Dedicated-Query-String-Filtering`

Все отлично работает, но я не знаю даже как можно организовать правильно ссылки на фильтры. 
 
К примеру есть фильтр с производителями, делаю ссылки вот так `{{ url(Request::url() . '?brand=1') }}` урл такой получается (http://site.app/cat/laptops?brand=1) 
 При нажатии все работает. Но если я нажму на второй фильтр, к примеру "*есть в продаже*", то выводятся результаты с товарами которые есть в продаже,а результаты с производителями пропадают. Вопрос в том, как можно прилепить 2-5 фильтров друг к другу? 
 То есть вот так:`brand=1&in_stock=true&price=300'`
Может как нибудь на jquery можно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В laravel 5.2.22 появилась функция `Request::fullUrlWithQuery()`

> Если вам необходимо добавить параметры к текущему значению url то, теперь вы можете взять текущий запрос и добавить к нему массив. Пример: ваш текущий URL - site.com/catalog и вы хотите новый URL , site.com/catalog?category=1&order=price :

`$request->fullUrlWithQuery(['category' => '1', 'order' => 'price']);`
Работает также на добавление к уже имеющимся параметрам.